# JSON value modified after receiving HTTP request

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, vue.js, axios

I'm doing a request from my VueJS client to a Nodejs server + MySQL database to obtain a "competition" and all his properties. And after that I build an object to send it to my client (VueJS). The request is made by Axios and the server uses Express.

The problem is that one of the properties of the competition is an array of Teams, and other property is Rounds that contain Matches that also contains Teams (same teams of the array of Teams but only 2 for every Match). So when I send the request the object looks like this:
(console.log(competition))

```
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'competition1',
  season: '19/20',
  manager: 4,
  teams: [
    {
      id: 11,  //pay attention to this property
      name: 'team1',
      manager: null,
      season: '19/20',
      competition: 3
    },
    {
      id: 12,   //pay attention to this property
      name: 'team2',
      manager: null,
      season: '19/20',
      competition: 3
    }
  ],
  rounds: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Round 1',
      date: '2019-11-22T23:00:00.000Z',
      competition: 3,
      matches: [
        {
          id: 2,
          localTeam: {
            id: 12,
            name: 'team2',
            manager: null,
            season: '19/20',
            competition: 3
          },
          awayTeam: {
            id: 11,
            name: 'team1',
            manager: null,
            season: '19/20',
            competition: 3
          },
          matchDay: '2019-11-23T23:00:00.000Z',
          round: 1,
          competition: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but the object I'm receiving in the client is this one:

```
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'competition1',
  season: '19/20',
  manager: 4,
  teams: [
    {
      id: undefined, //changed to UNDEFINED
      name: 'team1',
      manager: null,
      season: '19/20',
      competition: 3
    },
    {
      id: undefined,   //changed to UNDEFINED
      name: 'team2',
      manager: null,
      season: '19/20',
      competition: 3
    }
  ],
  rounds: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Round 1',
      date: '2019-11-22T23:00:00.000Z',
      competition: 3,
      matches: [
        {
          id: 2,
          localTeam: {
            id: 12,
            name: 'team2',
            manager: null,
            season: '19/20',
            competition: 3
          },
          awayTeam: {
            id: 11,
            name: 'team1',
            manager: null,
            season: '19/20',
            competition: 3
          },
          matchDay: '2019-11-23T23:00:00.000Z',
          round: 1,
          competition: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that the only difference is that the teams ID is being set to UNDEFINED but I don't know why. There is any reason? Here I post the code that I'm using to build the Competition object:

```
competitionService.findById(id).then((result => {    
    if (result) {     
      let competition = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0]))
      teamService.findByCompetition(id).then((teams => {
        competition.teams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(teams))        
        roundService.findByCompetition(id).then((rounds => {          
          competition.rounds = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rounds))
          matchService.findByCompetition(id).then((matches => {
            for (let i = 0; i < competition.rounds.length; i++) {
              competition.rounds[i].matches=[]
              for (let j = 0; j < matches.length; j++) {
                for (let k = 0; k < teams.length; k++) {
                  if (matches[j].localTeam == teams[k].id) {
                    matches[j].localTeam = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(teams[k]))
                  }
                  if (matches[j].awayTeam == teams[k].id) {
                    matches[j].awayTeam = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(teams[k]))
                  }
                }
                if (competition.rounds[i].id == matches[j].round) {
                  competition.rounds[i].matches.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(matches[j])))
                }
              }
            }
            console.log(competition)              
            res.status(200).send({
              competition: competition
            })
          }))
        }))
      })) 
    }
  })
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: To be clear, if you hit your API endpoint directly, not using Vue at all just hitting it, do you get the undefined still?

Comment: Yes! I forgot to comment it, thanks. In postman for example I receive the ids correctly.

Comment: It looks like you only assign teams here,  competition.teams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(teams)). Why are you stringifying and then parsing it? To break any references? Also, if you console.log(teams) are the ID values ok?

Comment: Yes, to break references and because when it comes form MySQL it's a RowDataPacket. And yes, the values in that point are ok. Also the values in the last console log before sending it are ok

Comment: If you look in your browser's devtools, is the response there ok?

Comment: I have the VueJS extension and the response arrives with the undefined values

Comment: Ok but to be clear, what do the Network devtools tell you - not the VueJS extension.

Comment: Same as the VueJS extension, id = undefined

Comment: Ok so that confirms it's 100% on the server side, not a Node issue. If you console.log right after competition.teams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(teams)), do you see the issue? This assumes you can check server logs.

Comment: No, I can't see the issue there, only when I console.log in the client side.

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense. So going back to my comment about checking the Network tab, if you copy the URL of the request to your API and open it in a new tab, the data is ok?

Comment: It looks like it's the client? Because in Postman the response is OK but in the other client (Vue) it's not.

Comment: Alrighty - well then I'd begin by commenting out the code after `let competition = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0]))` and check to see if it's fine there - it should be - and then gradually add it back in. You should see something screw it up.

Comment: I think that is not a code issue, probably it's the way that the client (or the http request client) are treating the data. Maybe when it identifies duplicated data as "teams" in this case, it skips the id of one of these objects to not duplicate it. And maybe thats why in Postman the response is shown correctly, because Postman just show you all the response and not treat the data.